# Api for receive data from callback url

Tags: c#, api, callback

I search in google and here but I got weird case.

I need to make an API, what get data from another service where I paste links to my API.

Links should be that:

```
1: https://myAPI/xxx/xxxx/optincallbackurl.php?email=$email$&key=sha1($email$security_parameter)
2: https://myAPI/xxx/xxxx/optincallbackurl.php?email=$email$&key=sha1($email$security_parameter)
```

Service in 2 options send me an email. How receive this data? Normal POST method API in c# should work for that callback?

Comment: First, the remote address accepts the Post request or Get. The second format in which it returns the data. Json?

Comment: Please add the C# code you have tried and the specific challenge you have with it and how we my assist you in fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask for advice how to make receiver from URI, I resolve my problem code below.

```
public class Kontakt
    {
        public string kEmail { get; set; }
    }
public class optoutcallbackurlController : ApiController
{
public void Post([FromUri]string email)
{
Kontakt kontakt = new Kontakt();
kontakt.kEmail = email;

}
}
```

Now I got link like myAPI/conroler?email="email.test@gmail.com" and I receive email from URI to my API.